# Is the Gigabyte Brix (GB-BXBT-2807) compatible with Ubuntu 14.04?

Tags: 14.04, compatibility

I'm not sure if it is true, but I have a feeling a lot of companies will neglect to state whether or not non-standard operating systems are supported, in order to save themselves the hassle of the additional support overhead. With this in mind and their [online spec](http://www.gigabyte.com/products/product-page.aspx?pid=5038#sp) for the GB-BXBT-2807 (which white-lists WIN7-WIN8.1), does anyone know if it will run Ubuntu 14.04? I will probably want to run Ubuntu 14.04.2 LTS server.

Comment: https://www.reddit.com/r/kodi/comments/33ca6u/latest_rev_of_kodi_running_ubuntu_1404_on_a/

Comment: Thanks. I'm not going to set up a media centre so hopefully this won't apply but duly noted.

Comment: I'm running Lubuntu 16.04 on a Gigabyte Brix GB-BXBT-2807. Had problems with stuttering audio/video which I fixed by setting `realtime-scheduling = no` in `/etc/pulse/daemon.conf` everything else works just fine, though.

Comment: I can confirm that in 2020 the installation of Ubuntu 18.04 is much easier than it was at the time of asking this question and you will not run into any major difficulties.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Ubuntu does run quite well on this device, but it won't be supported by the device manufacturer.

Here is a blog post by someone who installed Ubuntu on this device.  Apparently everything worked, even the Wifi adapter.

http://nucblog.net/2014/11/gigabyte-brix-2955u-review/

> I have a feeling a lot of companies will neglect to state whether or not non-standard operating systems are supported

By definition, they are not supported.  If you choose to put a different OS onto a computer, the company that sold the computer is not going to provide support to you.  However, that doesn't mean it won't work.

The Brix is a fairly standard x86/64 PC architecture with a traditional BIOS, Intel HD graphics etc.

Answer (score 1):

I installed Linux Mint 18 and the performance was good, but the device freezes playing movies.  with windows the performance was better.  With Korora 23 (a Fedora fork) do not even boot, exits to emergency command line boot prompt.

Comment: My Linux Mint 18 installation works perfectly, but had to update Bios settings ... there are a few settings that are incompatible with the current Linux kernel.

Comment: I had a similar problem using Majaro, it seemed to be solved by downgrading the kernel to 3.16 or earlier.